# change margins on col-xs-* in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How to change the margins on `col-xs-*` or col margins

[image]

Comment: try `@media screen and (min-width: 320px and max-height: 480px) { .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9  { margin-left: 0; } }`

Comment: can you provide it in jsfiddle

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/Cy9vmHXUMH#

Comment: The above links works perfectly in mobile, do you want it in desktop also?

Answer (score 0):

The column margins/gutters are not built with margins, but with padding.

When using the sass/less version of Bootstrap, you can change it in the general variables.less file.
When not using the less version, you can use this (setting the gutter on 5px):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated the code snippet and tested on a basic bootstrap installation.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you can also use offset before your first col.

For example :

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```